# How can I create an anchor link in a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-docs

Let's take the following example document:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I create an anchor link for the heading "How to boost sales" to share this document position with another user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a *bookmark*.

Place the cursor where you want to link to, and select *Insert → Bookmark* from the menu. 
[image: The Insert -> Bookmark menu item]

Click the *Link* item in the popup menu:
[image: The Bookmark popup menu]

The browser location bar now shows the URL to the bookmark, which you can forward to other users (that have access to the document, of course).

[image: The browser URL bar]

Comment: A word of caution: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89335/moving-google-docs-bookmarks indicates Google does not provide movment reliably (or at least that question does not yet have an answer).

Answer (score 5):

Beyond adding bookmarks, every document heading (Format > Paragraph Styles) automatically makes an anchor.  You can see the URL change as you navigate through the different headings.

Comment: Exactly what I'm after! Copy the link from the address bar when the cursor is in the heading and add that elsewhere in the document, send to other people etc...